# How do I change the source of the images in this table?

Tags: html, css

code http://jsbin.com/ratohaxiya/1/edit?html,css,output

for instance I want to use single png file for the Hawks logo instead of taking them from [here](http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/W37LXqFl81W0RjPh7ed7Ru-AzkTahmzCAT-6n4IV-Nk.png) 
img src does not work and i have to keep the background colors the same

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use many image files for a large set of small icons since it will effect page load time negatively. Each individual file is requested from the server and often times waiting for a reply takes significantly longer than the actual download.

However, if you opt to do so then replace current code that locates the position of each icon in the CSS file.

Replace This:

```
a[href$="/r/ATLANTAHAWKS#S"]:before {
  background-position: 2px 1px!important
}
```

With this using your own filepaths:

```
a[href$="/r/ATLANTAHAWKS#S"]:before {
  background-image: url("hawks-filepath.png");
}
```

This change shouldn't affect your background color since it wasn't part of the image sprite sheet.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer you should mark it as correct so others don't invest their time reading your question only to realize it has been answered.